# Bootstrap Form Helpers states.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-form-helper

I have a form to collect country and states from the user. I am using the bootstrap-formhelpers-states.js library to collect this data. But when I vardump the post array that is submitted, only the shortcodes of the states and country is sent.

My question is the same as this [Bootstrap form helper not picking complete country name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632201/bootstrap-form-helper-not-picking-complete-country-name/43886869?noredirect=1#comment74807916_43886869)

but that too has not been answered. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that codes are the values given to select options. You can use jquery to change the values of each option by the text for each. Might work.

```
        <script>                
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#selectId > option").each(function() {
                    $(this).val($(this).text());
                    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
                });                   

            });                
        </script>
```

Comment: Thank you but I have changed to another library. This library has been abandoned by the creators.